# Target only 1 button in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

Im getting the values in a div from the DB and displaying using `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-controller = "myTest">
    <div ng-repeat="name in names">
        <h4>{{name.name}}</h4>
            <button ng-class="{'active': isActive}" ng-click="test()" >me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.test= function(){
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
}
```

I have defined a class isActive in my css and that is applied/removed to the button on click. There are 5 results so 5 `divs` are created cause of `ng-repeat` and 5 `buttons`(1 for each respective div). The problem is that every button (all 5 of them) is getting that class. I want the class to be applied/removed only to the button clicked. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this :

```
<div ng-controller="myTest">
    <div ng-repeat="name in names">
        <h4>{{name.name}}</h4>
        <button ng-class="{ active : name.isActive }"
                ng-click="name.isActive = !name.isActive">me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I created an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvfvdnuz/)

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/angular-best-practices-ng-repeats-index came across this and this is my error now

Comment: I edit my answer and I try it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xof0w9tj/). You don't need the fonction `$scope.test(index)` in your controller anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of each button status.

One way will be to passing the name or anything that uniquely identify the button to your function:

```
<div ng-controller = "myTest">
    <div ng-repeat="name in names">
        <h4>{{name.name}}</h4>
            <button ng-class="{'active': buttons[name].isActive}" ng-click="test(name)" >me</button>
    </div>
</div>  

$scope.buttons = {};

$scope.test= function(name){
    $scope.buttons[name].isActive = !$scope.buttons[name].isActive;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. Nothing happens. I changed it to `name.name` like: `ng-class="{'active': buttons[name.name].isActive}"` and also the `test(name.name)` since `name.name` is only unique and `name` has no value cause im using `ng-repeat`. Still doesn't work. I understand your logic but how can i pass some identity when using `ng-repeat`.

Comment: You can use the index internal to ng-repeat and pass test($index) in your ng-click attribute.

Comment: Tried `ng-click="test($index)"` with and without `buttons[name.name]`. Its not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Foi0c?p=preview) that answers this question without modifying your source array.

Your function becomes

```
  vm.test = function(buttonIndex) {
      //Clear the class if you press the same button again
      if (vm.buttonIndex === buttonIndex) {
        vm.buttonIndex = undefined;
      } else {
        vm.buttonIndex = buttonIndex;
      }

    };
```

And your HTML is

```
 <div ng-repeat="name in main.names track by $index">
    <h4>{{name.name}}</h4>
    <button ng-class="{'active': main.buttonIndex===$index}" ng-click="main.test($index)">me</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/angular-best-practices-ng-repeats-index came across this and this is my error now

Comment: Updated my plunk to use the object and only left the index in the track by.